# How do I check if a query exists in the query cache?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, caching

Using NHibernate, how can I check if the query I am executing already exist in the query cache or not programmatically?

Comment: The whole point of high-level caches is that they are transparent.

Comment: @Diego: I have function A() that when it is called on a non-cached query will take very long but has a very efficient way to access the cache. On the other hand I have function B() which is faster on loading from the db (and thus saving the query on the cache) but doesn't fetch from the cache. So I need to know if it's already cached or not.

Comment: If you need such fine grained control, use the underlying cache manually instead of the query cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx. This article has a sample which retrieves the query plan for a specific query (under section 'A. Clearing a query plan from the plan cache'):

```
SELECT plan_handle, st.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
WHERE text LIKE N'SELECT * FROM Person.Address%';
```

This however is not integrated into NHibernate and you will have to know the SQL code for your query.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to throw SQL Profiler on. If you see the query hitting the database then it's not in the cache.

Comment: Nice idea but I meant how to do this programmatically.